# How to add custom class to functions in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress website on localhost, and I want an add to cart button.
I've used a wordpress function for the same, but I  need design that of what I've made.
The function I've used is:
print_wp_cart_button_for_product()

I just wanted to know how do I add class to the button which is generated from the above function.

Thanks

Comment: Find where the function is, and modify the output? Or create an attribute to be entered when you call the function such as `print_wp_cart_button_for_product('btn btn-default')`. Did you create the function yourself?

Comment: No, the function is a wordpress function, I did not make it,

Comment: You could add a CSS class with jQuery, for example.

Comment: Hmm it looks like it's part of the Wordpress Simple PayPal Shopping Cart plugin, and not Wordpress core. YOu might be better off asking them, as it's part of their plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the correct solution to your problem, but what you could do is inspect which classes/id there are already added (in your browser > inpect).
You could define these classes in your CSS and override them with your own styling.

Comment: WHilst this is a good solution, as you pointed out it's not what the OP is after. Plus there is a flaw, if the classes generated by the plugin authors decides to change at some point, then the CSS class would need to be updated. The ability to add another class to the buttons when generated would be the best solution.

Comment: You are right Lee! Unfortunately I don't have the solution to that.